# Extend Linux partition in Dual boot with Windows without losing data?

Tags: partition

I've the following partitions on my hard drive (copied from Gparted):

[image]

As you can see:

- **ext4 Linux HOME** partition
- THEN ==> **windows (8.1) ntfs** partition
- THEN ==> **178 GB of UNUSED space** (I got it by resizing **from the end** ntfs partition)

The problem here is that it seems **I can't free space BEFORE ntfs partition** to make free space to **extend ext4 home partition** because this would mean moving ntfs start sector, i.e. , (maybe?) corrupt Windows boot.

Any suggestion?
How should I do to pass from the situation shown in the image above to ext4 partition with about 100 GB space?

Comment: is there any way to mount permanently one partition on boot start?

Comment: Moving and resizing can be risky. In Linux you can mount any partition anywhere basically so why not investigate simply creating a partition in your unallocated space and mounting it wherever you want, for instance inside your /home dir... Take a look at your [/etc/fstab file](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MoveMountpointHowto) for permanent mounting assignments...

Comment: The answer to your main question is `It's impossible without removing Windows.` and the answer to your comment is given by @illuminÉ. So, @illuminÉ, will you take the honor of answering the question (like: not in a comment)?

Comment: @TheJustist I hear you but this is not even 24hrs old. There is an opportunity for OP to look into it and bring his own solution as it applies to his setup. In any case you're welcome to contribute an answer!

Answer (score 1):

I cannot figure out why don't simply move the /home to the unallocated space. If you really need that partition layout just grab an spare disk to write it and move everything over it and finally clone it back overwriting your original config

Disclaimer: I cannot comment yet

Comment: sound a good idea. how shall I move /home to unallocated space?

Comment: that's pretty easy actually, just create a new ext4 partition of the desired size with gparted and mount it to a temporary folder to let's say `/newhome` (you need to create it before). Then copy everything with` cp -r /home/* /newhome`. When you are done change your `/etc/fstab` to reflect the changes, now /home should be mapped to `/dev/sda7` rather than `/dev/sda6` (assuming sda7 is your new partition). To check that everything is fine check that the size of /home and /newhome is the same with `du -s /home` and `du -s /newhome`. then you should be able to remove the old partition

Comment: Ok, I opened fstab with emacs. I have this line "UUID=794025be-c11e-4437-aecb-dec326b7ffa1 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2" (not dev/sdX is written). What shall I modify?

Comment: In the `/etc/fstab` file itself you have a reference to the `blkid` command which gives you a map between each `/dev/sdaX` and it's `UUID`.

Comment: I'm consused. There is a reference to blkid command. However when I type it in terminal (either alone or followed by "/dev/sda7" string there is no output. IN fstab file each row is like "UUID=c6106669-bfaa-4485-9df8-58fea5b3e008 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0" . What should I do exactly?

Comment: sorry, you need to run it with `sudo`, so `sudo blkid` will show you the mapping

Comment: thank you very much. It's worked! Just more thing: since also /sda2 is quite small and I guessed is where packages and OS are installed (right?), is there any way to install all new packages on /sda7 which is much bigger?

Comment: It's perfectly feasible simply copying and changing the mount point BUT you will need to re-install grub as you will move /boot along. I don't suggest you to do it till you run out of space as it's more flexible to have a separated /home partition.

Comment: how  shall I reinstall grub? and why do you say it's more flexible? thanks again

Comment: This applies to any distro http://askubuntu.com/a/142704 . Guessing that you have a Debian-Ubuntu flavoured distro this applies https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing. I think all this stuff has been very well answered in thousands of places so for DRY sake use the search and keep the thread focused ;)